# NTP server for test

Tags: server, ntp

I'm trying to configure an ntp server to test my client.
The ntp server hasn't to be synced on real ntp, I would like to manage myself the clock.

here is the current config:

```
# /etc/ntp.conf, configuration for ntpd; see ntp.conf(5) for help

listen on *

restrict 127.0.0.1

disable auth
broadcastclient

server 127.127.1.0 iburst
fudge 127.127.1.0 stratum 10
```

the client get this response:

```
step time server my_server_ip offset -113.084299 sec
```

It seems that the "step time" means the server is not synced.

If my understanding is correct, the response has to start by "adjust time"